# Send one Email to Multiple Addresses in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to create code that takes a line that contains the address and sends an email to all addresses in the same email. But my code sends the email only to the first address on the list and does not add the others.

```js
function sendMail(){
 

 
  var sheetMail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ecrvc = sheetMail.getSheetByName('List');
  
  var lastecrvc = ecrvc.getLastRow(); 
   
  //var email = [];
  var people = ",";
  var subject = "Hello All";
  var message = "This is a test";
  var email =  ecrvc.getRange("B2:B"+lastecrvc).getValues();
   

  
  for(var i = 9; i<lastecrvc; i++){
     var emailTo = ecrvc.getRange(i,2).getValues(); 
     email = emailTo + "@gmail.com"; 
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message)
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like `MailApp` to send a single email to multiple recipients, you can use a comma separated email string as the first argument of `MailApp.sendEmail`. For example:

```js
const emails = [ "john.doe@email.com", "jane.doe@email.com" ]

// Join the emails into a single string separated by commas
const combinedEmails = emails.join() // "john.doe@email.com,jane.doe@email.com"

MailApp.sendEmail(combinedEmails, subject, message)
```

That ought to work. But do verify that you are correctly reading the email addresses from the sheet. If you aren't sure, you could share a sample sheet with identical arrangement as the one you are using.

Assuming that you are reading the email addresses from the spreadsheet correctly, you can modify your last `for` loop slightly to generate a combined email string, and then send the email *outside* the loop:

```js
var emailsList = [];
for(var i = 9; i<lastecrvc; i++) {
  var emailTo = ecrvc.getRange(i,2).getValues(); 
  email = emailTo + "@gmail.com";
  emailsList.push(email);
}
var combinedEmails = emailsList.join();
MailApp.sendEmail(combinedEmails, subject, message);
```

Comment: But I want to do that geting the values (emails) from the table. If I change the address I just change in spreadsheet. I want to make it using the function [for]

Comment: Sure, that can be done. Have added a snippet at the end of my answer.